# Error C3892: You cannot assign to a variable that is const

Tags: c++, constants, sfml

I am making a game in C++. I haven't started coding the game yet, I'm setting up the different classes and making the menu. This is my first time making a "big" program and I find myself making everything static. When I make everything in my classes static I for some reason need to make the variables const

```
error C2864: 'GameWindow::ScreenHeight': a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type
```

When I made them const I get another error:

```
error C3892: 'ScreenHeight': you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

Here is my GameWindow class:

```
class GameWindow {
public:
    static sf::RenderWindow mainWindow;

    static void SetScreenWidth(int x);
    static int GetScreenWidth();
    static void SetScreenHeight(int x);
    static int GetScreenHeight();

    static void Initialize();

private:
    static const int ScreenWidth = 1024;
    static const int ScreenHeight = 576;
};
```

For some reason I can't do this

```
void GameWindow::SetScreenHeight(int x) {
    ScreenHeight = x;
}
```

I know what's causing the problem - I can't change the value of a const integer - but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: const = constant = immutable = cannot be changed. Btw shouldn't every GameWindow instance have their own width and height?

Comment: Why are you making all these members `static` anyway?

Comment: why do you manage information on the screen in the GameWindow class? Shouldn't you have a singleton Screen class?

Comment: @i4h As I said this is my first big program so excuse me for doing everything wrong. You need to start somewhere, right? I fixed the errors but now I have 9 "unresolved external symbol" errors. They have something to do with the libraries or the files and I can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: @bames53 I need your help ^

Comment: @zenith I need your help ^

Comment: Seems like a new question? If so, post it as such.

Comment: I need to wait 32 more minutes. I'm in a hurry

Comment: @zenith forgot to mention you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **declare** the variables in the class definition and **define** them outside:

In the header file:

```
class GameWindow {
    /* Whatever here... */

    private:
    static int ScreenWidth;
    static int ScreenHeight;
};
```

And in the source file:

```
int GameWindow::ScreenWidth = 1024;
int GameWindow::ScreenHeight = 576;
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I make everything in my classes static I for some reason need to make the variables const.

No, you don't. You need to define them in the .cpp file if you want them to be static *and* non-const.

Or better yet, make them non-static in the first place. It doesn't make sense for all `GameWindow`s to share the same width and height, and the same `RenderWindow`.

Also, what's up with the `Initialize` method? The *constructor* of the class should do the initialization.

Time to rethink your design. Avoid `static`, avoid public member variables, avoid non-constructor initialization methods. *Especially* if this is a big project.

Answer (score 0):

In writing `static const int ScreenWidth = 1024;`, you are telling the compiler that `ScreenWidth` cannot be changed. (The compiler can then make all sorts of optimisations - perhaps eliminating the constant from the code altogether).

So attempting to change it will issue a compiler warning.

If you want to be able to change it, drop the `const` (along with the assignment in the class declaration), and *define* the variable in exactly one compilation unit using the statement

`int GameWindow::ScreenWidth = 1024;`